# Drupal 7 - Print Module - Choose content to print

Tags: drupal-7, printing-web-page

I am using the Print module in my Drupal 7 site (www.kooknet.be).
How can I choose which fields are printed in my custom content type?
I already added the "print-page" class to several HTML tags, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: It could be tons of places, you need to elaborate on what the error you're receiving and what you've done to reproduce and/or attempt to resolve the issue. It's probably a simple fix, but based on your question... who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the Print module installed, you can set which fields are displayed for the 'print' view mode easily from the admin interface!

1. Go to the 'Manage Display' screen for your content type: /admin/structure/types/manage//display
2. Once you enable the Print module, you should start seeing a 'Print' display option in the collapsed list of display options available
   [image]
3. Check that display option (**and** any others that are relevant to your content type) and hit 'Save'
4. Now you'll see that that display option is added and you can add or hide fields from it as you please!

:-)